# Getting Exception in thread "ClientThread 1" org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException when trying to connect Redis (ElastiCache)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, redis

I have created Redis (ElastiCache) on AWS and I am trying to connect it using following code:-

```
Config config = new Config();       
config.useClusterServers().addNodeAddress("redis://XXXXXX.cache.amazonaws.com:6379");
RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);
```

When I run the jar on the instance which contain above code, it gives me error as:-

```
    Exception in thread "ClientThread 1" org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to Redis server: /127.0.0.1:6379
        at org.redisson.connection.pool.ConnectionPool$2$1.operationComplete(ConnectionPool.java:137)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:481)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:122)
        at org.redisson.misc.RedissonPromise.tryFailure(RedissonPromise.java:83)
        at org.redisson.connection.pool.ConnectionPool.promiseFailure(ConnectionPool.java:306)
        at org.redisson.connection.pool.ConnectionPool.access$400(ConnectionPool.java:53)
        at org.redisson.connection.pool.ConnectionPool$4.operationComplete(ConnectionPool.java:276)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:500)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:479)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:122)
        at org.redisson.misc.RedissonPromise.tryFailure(RedissonPromise.java:83)
        at org.redisson.client.RedisClient$2$1$2.run(RedisClient.java:225)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:6379
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:323)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:340)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:633)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        ... 11 more
```

**Note**:-I can successfully able to connect to Redis (ElastiCache) from the instance using Redis-cli.

Comment: Is the keystore in your JRE upto date ?

Comment: Yes, it's up to date

Comment: Can you try the steps here https://gist.github.com/4ndrej/4547029  , I am assuming that its something with the JRE keystore because redis-cli works fine for you.

Comment: I removed the SSL problem using redis instead of rediss.
But now it's giving me this exception:-
Exception in thread "ClientThread 1" org.redisson.client.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to Redis server: /127.0.0.1:6379

Comment: What does "netstat -patln | grep 6379" give you ? This is to check if redis is listening on 127.0.0.1 interface.

Comment: I am getting this result:- No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=500 but you should be root.